# I want to install tlp via PPA on 22.10 and find I can't

Tags: apt, updates, power-management, ppa, 22.10

I want to install tlp for battery saver on my laptop. I added the ppa:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
```

I get this error message in the log:

```
    Err:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu kinetic Release
      404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
    Reading package lists... Done                                  
    E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The Ubuntu version I use is 22.10.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, there is no PPA for this package for Ubuntu 22.10. You installed a PPA that doesn't exist. You should remove it and find another way to install tlp (is it not available in the repos? It's available for 22.04).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I'm confused. Is the current version not 1.5.0, dated 2022-01-07? (That's what I'm running, and if I've overlooked something I'd like to fix that.)

Comment: You're right -- I'm the one that's confused.  I was looking at the bionic package list by mistake :-/.  Currently there doesn't appear to be any reason to use the PPA, and presumably it will be updated for Kinetic when there's a new TLP release.